# Element external-media-path is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to include:

```
<external-media-path name="name" path="path" />
```

But Android Studio is showing me warning:

> Element external-media-path is not allowed here

Minimum SDK version of my app is 21.
How to fix this?

Comment: If you ignore the message, does your app build and run correctly? If yes, then this may just be a Lint bug. That is a relatively new `FileProvider` feature IIRC, and the Lint rule may not have caught up.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for replying. Yes, if I ignore this warning then application runs perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio has a set of "inspections", implemented in the IDE, independent of the Lint system. You are getting a warning from the "Android XML element is not allowed" inspection, because it is not up to date with the latest `FileProvider`.

I can reproduce the problem on Android Studio 3.4.2, and I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138132330) for it. If you are using a newer version of Android Studio and still see the problem, if you could, add a comment on that issue.

In the meantime, ignore the apparently-erroneous warning.

Comment: Thank for answering question and filling issue on Google bug tracker :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: The issue was with `external-media-path`. I know the example you have given works.